# Статические методы абстрактного класса Delegate

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.

Если посмотреть определение класса Delegate, то видим следующее:

```
public abstract class Delegate : ICloneable, ISerializable
```

Но среди статических методов данного класса много тех, что возвращают экземпляр абстрактного(!) класса Delegate. Например :

```
public static Delegate CreateDelegate(Type type, MethodInfo method)
```

или массив делегатов :

```
public virtual Delegate[] GetInvocationList();
```

Каким образом это возможно? Ведь внутри такого метода должно быть прописано что-то типа:

```
Delegate d = new Delegate(arg1,arg2); // но это ведь неправильно
return d;
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том что класс Delegate находится на низком уровне .net Framework, а это как бы граница между com и .net платформами поэтому он возвращает обернутый com объект.

```
//...
Delegate @delegate = Delegate.InternalAlloc(type.TypeHandle.GetRuntimeType());
if (!@delegate.BindToMethodName(target, (RuntimeType)target.GetType(), method, (DelegateBindingFlags)26 | (ignoreCase ? DelegateBindingFlags.CaselessMatching : ((DelegateBindingFlags)0))))
{
  if (throwOnBindFailure)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_DlgtTargMeth"));
  }

  @delegate = null;
}

return @delegate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Наличие в абстрактном классе статических методов - это распространенная идиома. Она, например, применяется в паттерне [Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29), для сокрытия конкретных классов иерархии наследования.

Более простым примером статического метода, который возвращает абстрактный базовый класс в .NET - [`WebRequest.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public abstract class WebRequest
{
    public static WebRequest Create(Uri requestUri)
    {
       // Будет создан экземпляр HttpWebRequest, но
       // у разработчика этого метода есть возможность
       // изменить свое решение в будущем.
    } 
}
```

Разработчик базового класса иногда знает о возможных типах наследников и может создавать экземпляр нужного типа, например, в зависимости от переданных аргументов статического метода.

В случае делегатов, это позволяет скрыть разработчикам CLR/.NET Framework класс MulticastDelegate, доступ к которому напрямую у нас, как у пользователей, отсутствует.